# liferay 7 single-approver-definition.xml location

Tags: liferay, workflow, liferay-7

I would like  to edit the single appover definition workflow in liferay 7.
Does anyone know where the file single-approver-definition.xml  is located in liferay 7 CE?

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for github and choose [this one](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-portal-workflow/tree/7.0.x/portal-workflow-kaleo-runtime-impl/src/main/resources/META-INF/definitions). An alternate solution is to hunt it down in all of Liferay's jars (if you want to be sure to get the one that's packaged with Liferay). The github address gives you a hint as to which jar file to take a closer look at.

Comment: Yep, as Olaf says, you can get it from the Liferay src code or from the Kaleo Runtime Impl JAR (`com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.runtime.impl-2.0.5.jar` in 7.0 GA2). In the JAR it's in `META-INF/definitions`. Note that there are actually several definitions in there that you can install, and edit to suit your purposes.

Comment: I should have added that the JAR is inside your Liferay installation's `Liferay CE Forms and Workflow.lpkg`, which is in the `osgi/marketplace` folder.